# Easy Analytics Tool for Ionic 4 Android and IOS

Tags: android, ios, ionic4, analytics, ionic-native

I have been struggling to integrate google analytics, firebase analytics, flurry analytics and every time I try to compile my gradle files after following tutorials it always fails for some other reason. Does anyone know which analytic tool is easy to use and if there are any tutorials for them? I have read and tried so many things and I'm not sure what to do now.

Any help would be amazing, cheers!

Below is my ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (C:\Users\riley.grice\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.24
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.21
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.1.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.9.0
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0) : 0.2.9

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\riley.grice\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Sorry for the late  response what is that you exartly facing when integrating flurry can you post your error logs.